# PDF embedding issue with Goudy Initialen

Tags: fonts, publishing

I'm using the [Goudy Initialen](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/goudyinitialen/) along with the `lettrine` package to create dropcap letters at the beginning of each chapter.

I'm using pdfLaTeX (so the Type 1 version of the font):

```
\input GoudyIn.fd
\newcommand*\initgoudy{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}

\chapter{Chapter Title}

\lettrine[lines=3,nindent=0.0em,loversize=0.3]{\initgoudy E}{xample of} paragraph at the beginning of chapter etc.....
```

The PDF looks fine on my computer, and when I check the properties through Adobe Reader (or Acrobat), all fonts appear embedded, as they should.

However, when I try to publish the document through Kindle Direct Publishing (KDP: A Print-on-Demand self-publishing platform), the Goudy initials don't display correctly on the previewer (everything else looks perfect). When I download the PDF proof of the book, Adobe Reader displays the following error message: "Cannot find or create the font 'GoudyInitialen'. Some characters may not display or print correctly."

Any way to fix this? Is this a LaTeX issue, or a KDP issue? My guess is that the Goudy font is not embedded correctly in the PDF, though I'm not sure.

EDIT: The more I research this, the more I become convinced the issue is with KDP rather than LaTeX. Still, if anyone has any ideas on how to fix this, please let me know.

EDIT 2: After experimenting a little, I found out the the issue goes away if you take the LaTeX-generated PDF, open it in Acrobat Reader, and then save it as a PDF/X (which you can do only if you have the "pro" version). I'm still not sure what the issue was as I don't really know enough about the various types of PDF-files, but for now it seems that the PDF is displaying correctly on the KDP site.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong but one option would be to make pdfs of just the letters you need and then replace `{\initgoudy E}` by `\includegraphics{goudy-E}` which the publishing software might be more happy with

Comment: How do you make PDFs of all the letters?

Comment: probably  some font tool could do that automatically but I'd probably just make a latex document that makes a 26 page pdf with one letter on each page and sized to just have the letter then you can use `\includegraphics[page=13]{zzz}` to  get an M

Comment: Probably I'll have to try this if no one offers a quicker or easier solution. Still, I'd like to find out what the issues is.

Comment: also it may not work, that is the end result would look Ok but since basically the included pdf would include the same font, you might end up back where you started, or you might not, it depends....

Comment: I don't know about PDFs, but I'm pretty sure that if I saved each character as a high-resolution image it would work. And the lettrine package lets you use images instead of characters. So no issue there. However, I'd much rather leave that as a last resort option.

Comment: To get images without loss of quality using FontForge, select the glyph you need and press `Ctrl-h`. In the window which opens, choose `File` and then `Export`. In the export window, choose `PDF` from the drop-down list. (You’ll need a fast machine to do this, because the Goudy initials are detailed.)